# Avoid possibly undefined value

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

In flow I have optional parameters a lot, like this:

```
type Props = {
   assets?: string[]
}
```

I only access these when I know for sure they are not undefined, however Flow keeps warning about "Property cannot be access on possibly undefined value".

[image]

However I know it is defined for sure, because I only call this method when it is defined. For instance like this:

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   filterAssets() {
       return this.props.assets.filter(....);
   }
   render() {
       return this.props.assets ? filterAssets() : null
   }
}

See I have a if statement there already. Is there anyway to avoid this warning, without adding real javascript logic just to hide this warning?

By real js logic I mean like in the method I want to avoid:

filterAssets() {
       if (!this.props.assets) return; // adding this line
       return this.props.assets.filter(....);
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do the refinement within `filterAssets`. Otherwise, that function could unsafely be called from elsewhere in the app.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { 
  props: {
    assets?: string[]
  }

  filterAssets() { 
    return this.props.assets 
      ? this.props.assets.filter(....) : null; 
  } 

  render() { 
    return this.filterAssets();
  } 
}
```

Alternately, you could refactor `filterAssets` to take a definitely typed `assets` property:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component { 
  props: {
    assets?: string[]
  }

  filterAssets(assets: string[]) { return assets.filter(....); } 

  render() { 
    const assets = this.props.assets;
    return assets ? this.filterAssets(assets) : null 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ohh "unsafely be called from elsewhere" that's a good point. I like your definitely typed idea alt too. Thanks for 2 solutions in one!

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Is there any other way to indicate to flow that assets is definitely typed?

Comment: You may be able to add a refinement function with `%checks`. See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4390

Comment: Oh wow that is very interesting looking! A hidden undocumented feature, thanks for your deep help!